# How to grab the download link that a software uses to download files?

Tags: download-manager, file-download

I've a software that downloads a file from internet. How could I capture the download link that the software is downloading files from and use it to download using my download manager instead?

I'm trying to look for a general method that captures the link(s) from which any software downloads its file from.

### Illustrative Examples

- Audible download manager downloads an audio book file [I need to capture the download link that audible is downloading from to use this link to download using my download manager instead.]
- Maya 3D Max installation file is a small file which downloads the actual install file which is huge. [I need to capture the download link of this file to download it using my download manager instead.]
- Kaspersky downloads its updates. [I need to capture the download links of the updates files to download them using my download manager instead.]
- And so on.

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific ? What is this "software" ? Any inkling as to what URL it's trying to access ? If you're talking about something like AV (Anti-Virus) , then its probably looking at some pre-defined FTP location. Are you interested in this FTP location by any chance ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar Actually, it's a lot of software, not just one. For example: Audible download manager downloads a book [I need to capture the download link that audible is downloading from and download it using my download manager]

Answer (score 0):

1. For direct download, you could use static URLs and it'll work fine. But I believe it's not your case.
2. For dynamic URLs, you can capture the download link by any HTTP monitoring tool. [Fiddler](http://www.getfiddler.com/) will capture request/response if downloader supports wininet proxy; Or you may have to set proxy in the downloader to route the request through Fiddler. For non-proxy supported applications, you may choose any one of [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=4865) or [Microsoft Message Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=44226) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

   - Websites may offer dynamic URLs that are only valid for particular session. So if you are capturing a generated (or calculated) URL, it may became invalid when you try with another session.
   - Cookies may be necessary for dynamic URLs. Downloaders like JDownloader, FDM and many other supports it.
   - Media files (e.g YouTube) downloaded by chunks and constructed to single file by downloaders. So the link you capture may point only to a part of the file.
   - By `Maya 3D Max installer` I guess you mean Akamai download providers. (They were used by Adobe and AutoDesk if I remember correct). In many cases they offer offline installers. So you may use those links.
   - AV programs might use propriety protocols for security reasons and the downloaded file constructed/unpacked/consumed by application. So I would suggest downloading the weekly or monthly offline update files.